# Why is there an extra "vav" when discussing the age range for the census of the Kehat family?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, parshat-nasso, bamidbar-parsha, census

Kudos to my shul's *chazzan* for pointing out this anomaly...

When discussing the census of Kehat, [Bemidbar 4:3](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=39995&st=&pgnum=19) says:

> מבן שלושים שנה ומעלה **ו**עד בן חמשים שנה

There is a vav before the word עד

But, when discussing the census of Gershon, in [Bemidbar 4:23](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=39995&st=&pgnum=24), it says:

> מבן שלושים שנה ומעלה עד בן חמשים שנה

without the vav.

Why is there this difference? Is there a difference in meaning?

**My surmisal**: Frequently, the Talmud discusses the Torah's meaning of the word עד as to whether it includes or excludes the upper numerical limit. However, I don't recall the Talmud discussing the difference of עד vs. ועד . The vav added to the word would mean "and". It seems like it would be an extra letter, in this context. Perhaps, the meaning of adding the vav would make it clear that age 50 is included for Kehat, but only until age 49 would be for Gershon?

Comment: Keeps the baal kriah awake ...

Comment: I don't recall seeing a similar distinction made elsewhere, though it would lend an interesting interpretation to "Ad **v'Ad Bichlal."**

Comment: There are many places in Chumash where there are seemingly extra vavs. I believe Rashi points some of them out but don't remember where offhand.

Comment: @Earl Careful - in a lot of cases, the darash is on the compound "v'et," not on the vav itself....

Comment: My question is: why does it say "umaala"

Comment: @Loewian Hey! You "stole" my question! I thought of that, also, but, I can only ask one at a time :-) :-) By all means, ask yours as well.

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky see Rashi to Vayishlach 36,24